# PHP error with HTML formring

Tags: php, html, forms

I am learning PHP from a book called [PHP and MySQL web development](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-Edition/dp/0672326728). I am a newbie to PHP , I am pretty well versed with C and HTML, I find syntax of PHP to be pretty same of C.

Look at the code:

```
<html>
<form action = "processorder.php" method = "post">
<p>tires:<input type=”text” name=”tireqty” size=”3” maxlength=”3” /></p>
<input type=”submit” value=”Submit Order” /></td>
</form>
</html>
```

This is the HTML code now I will type in the php code and save it as processorder.php

```
<?php
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’];
echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
$tireqty." tires<br />";
?>
```

After doing this , i go to the html page where I have to enter the value for tires and click submit after doing this it redirects to me mu processorder php page where my raw php code gets displayed and not the proper output which is:

```
Your order is as follows:
2 tires
```

But i get a different o/p which is as shown below:

```
 $tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’];
    echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
    $tireqty." tires<br />";
```

what is going on here what is wrong??? and i also get an error message is processorder script saying that:

```
parse error: undefined index 'tireqty' in line something and undefined var tireqty
```

Hey guys i dont know whats wrong but cant post comments that button is not working or my browser is not enabling me to write comments, I am answering to all the calls here:

Yeah I am using XAMPP what is wrong in that, what should i do?

I copied your codes and yes there are no errors in it but when i go to html page and click submit the browser opens a dialog box saying that "I have chosen to open process.php" and what should it do with it so i select open with gedit because that is the only default option available there, and it redirects to my php script page :(:(:(

WHat is this it is so tough, Is PHP really that difficult or am i working on a poor platform and learning from a bad book?

Is there any good book on php

Comment: the quotes of `$_POST[‘tireqty’];` does not looks quite correct take a look here for [the strings manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Always use ``isset`` to check whether the sent index is assigned or not with desired value

Comment: Create a blank page that only says: 
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and access it from your browser. If PHP is correctly installed, it should print a lot of information about your installation.

Comment: Yeah it is printing a lot of information i mean a lot right from version to license,

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’]; 
echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
$tireqty." tires<br />";
?>
```

You closed your echo tags in the first 2nd row already, therefor you need to add another echo tag to the 3rde line.

```
<?php
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’]; 
echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
echo $tireqty." tires<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Always make sure that your variables have been set before you use them:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['tireqty'])){

        $tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
        echo "<p>Your order is as follows: <br />";
        echo $tireqty." tires.</p>";

    }
 ?>
```

Also, your HTML had a random closing table column tag in it:

```
<html>
<form action = "processorder.php" method = "post">
<p>tires:<input type="text" name="tireqty" size="3" maxlength="3" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What is that isset??? I am new to php i am in like my 4th page please tell me the error

Comment: It determines whether a variable has been set before or not. i.e. whether or not it actually exists. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Its indeed handy Its a check function to see if the the variable is set (or if it contains an value) if so, it executes the block, if not, it won't. Its a good thing for debugging PHP. I agree here, that if you are learning PHP, you should indeed do it right and make sure you build in checks.

Comment: @Siddarth isset can check whether a certain variable or array has a value assigned to it or not. In the above case it will check whether the ``tireqty`` index is assigned with a value or not

Comment: Did exactly as you have shown here and no errors except a ']' bracket is missing in ur second line in php code, but now i get a message that what should firefx do as i have chosen to open process.php i choose open option but it opens my php script in text editor after opening so

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant â€˜tireqtyâ€™ - assumed 'â€˜tireqtyâ€™' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/mycodes/process.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: â€˜tireqtyâ€™ in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/mycodes/process.php on line 4

Your order is as follows:

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your PHP environment is not working as it should. Do you have a web server with PHP running or XAMP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)?

Comment: This is indeed the only answer that addresses the main problem stated in the OP though there are some other problems. I upvoted all good answers, but this is the best one.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant â€˜tireqtyâ€™ - assumed 'â€˜tireqtyâ€™' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/mycodes/process.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: â€˜tireqtyâ€™ in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/mycodes/process.php on line 4

Your order is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Always use

```
if ( isset($_POST['var']) ) { ... }
```

Same with `$_GET, $_SESSION` etc. You variable `tireqty` isn't initialized until form is submitted, that's why throws errors